# How to write relative path in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, path

I need to read a group of dat files so when I do this it is working all right.

```
 list_of_files=dir(fullfile('/home/username/Desktop/Old/MTP/Generate/schemes/o33smnpimp/data/', '*.dat'));
```

The thing is I want to do this for number of schemes (like o33smnpimp) where every scheme folder has a data folder so I tried something like this but it's not working. What could be the problem?

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('../data/', '*.dat'));
```

My matlab file lies in o33smnpimp folder.

Answer (score 1):

`..` indicates the parent directory, `.` the current directory. your code looks in `/home/username/Desktop/Old/MTP/Generate/schemes/` for the sub directory `data`, assuming your working directory is `/home/username/Desktop/Old/MTP/Generate/schemes/o33smnpimp`.

Use

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('./data/', '*.dat'));
```

or

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('data', '*.dat'));
```